# javascript how to get first 3 items from a list

Tags: javascript, list

I have a list of items and I need to get the first three items as another list
I have tried array.slice(0,3); but it returns 4 elements and it really is WAYYY TOO SLOW

Comment: How is it too slow? Could you show us the code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is slow here?  And slice(0,3) gives 3 elements, not 4

```js
const array = [...Array(100000)].map(e=>Math.random()*40|0)
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",() => console.log(array.slice(0,3)));
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button">Click</button>
```